# exact matching of string after hashtag

Tags: python-3.x

Return True if tweet contains a hashtag and exact match of defined tweetword

I have written a function that needs to (a) detects presence of "#" and (b) match the entire word after "#" with the input

```py
HASHTAG_SYMBOL = '#'
def contains_hashtag(tweet: str, tweetword: str) -> bool:

    if (HASHTAG_SYMBOL in tweet) and (tweetword in tweet):
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

When I run the function with 'example' input it gives me True but I need exact match i.e. since 'exampleABC' <> 'example' it should be False

contains_hashtag('I have #exampleABC for #class123', 'example')

Answer (score 3):

You should regex (re library).

```
import re

HASHTAG_SYMBOL = '#'
def contains_hashtag(tweet: str, tweetword: str) -> bool:
    if re.search(HASHTAG_SYMBOL + tweetword, tweet) is None:
        return False
    else: 
        return True
```

**edit**:
If you want to check it contains a whitespace character after the world use:

```
import re

HASHTAG_SYMBOL = '#'
def contains_hashtag(tweet: str, tweetword: str) -> bool:
    if re.search(HASHTAG_SYMBOL + tweetword + "\s", tweet) is None:
        return False
    else: 
        return True
```

**edit2:**
Don't use:

```
def foo():
    if condition:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You can use this instead:

```
def foo():
    return condition
```

So, better soulution will be:

```
import re

HASHTAG_SYMBOL = '#'
def contains_hashtag(tweet: str, tweetword: str) -> bool:
    return re.search(HASHTAG_SYMBOL + tweetword, tweet) is not None
```

Comment: contains_hashtag('I have #exampleABC for #class123', 'example')  results in True while should be False

Comment: contains_hashtag('I have #exampleABC for #class123', 'exampleABC') results in False while should be True

Comment: it appears to be working but how to switch True to False. thank you very much!

Comment: oh i swapped True and False :)